# Error: "unknown type name ip4addr_t"

Tags: c, types

I have a project to generate an IP address using the DHCP protocol. I found code that can help me so I tried to compile it in Ubuntu Linux using `gcc`. It found some errors; one of them is:

> unknown type name ip4addr_t

I don't know if this type is built-in in C, or in some `#include` I should add? Or should I create a specific type?

This the C code:

```
typedef ip4adress_t ipaddr_t;
union ip4addr_t
{
  .....
};
```

Comment: Difficult for us to guess what `ip4addr_t` should be. Only you have any real hope of being certain. Only you know what you are compiling.

Comment: normally ip4adress_t should be a type, in my question i tried to know if some #include is missed this is my question simply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed mean `ip4addr_t` then you wrote yourself that `ip4addr_t` is the name of a union.

```
union ip4addr_t
{
.....
};
```

So if you get an error that `ip4addr_t` is unknown type name then it means that some part of your code does not see this union definition.

Comment: i tried to search in all the code i don't find a definition of the union ip4adress_t

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the `ip4adress_t` is a typedef to `unsigned int`. However, it is not guaranteed to be the same for all platforms.

Comment: think you what i understand for you answer that the probem depend maybe of the plateform this code should run in windows i tried to make some changes to run in linux